# Carregar Marker G Maps a partir de While php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

Opa,

Tenho um arquivo .php com um while, onde me retornam vários registros com endereços, este arquivo está sendo chamado num include em minha index.
O while imprime várias divs onde dentro de cada uma tem outra div que é onde deverá ser exibido o mapa do google, com o marker do endereço.

Os markers no mapa são exibidos perfeitamente se inicio o javascript com coordenadas fictícias colocados na index, mas, como indicar as coordenadas reais com dados vindos de um while e iniciar o javascript, sendo que estes dados estão num include?

Javascript iniciado no Index, funciona beleza.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
function init() {
    var locations = [
                [40.6128,-73.9976, "images/pin-house.png", "estate-details-right-sidebar.html", "images/infobox-offer1.jpg", "Wall Street, Recife, BR", "R$120"]
            ];

            offersMapInit("offers-map",locations);
            mapInit(40.6128,-73.7903,"featured-map1","images/pin-house.png", false);
        }
```

O arquivo .php, que é incluido na index:

```
    <div class="featured-offers-container">
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="featured-offers-owl">
        <?php
            $data_atual = date("Y-m-d");

            $sql_lista=mysql_query(
                "
                    SELECT
                           cidade.name AS cidade_nome,
                           empresa.nome
                    FROM
                           cidade, empresa
                    WHERE
                           id_cidade = cidade.id AND
                           empresa.nome = 'blablabla'
                ");


            while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista))
            {

            echo'
                <div class="featured-offer-col">
                    <div class="featured-offer-front">

                        <div class="featured-offer-text">
                            <h4 class="featured-offer-title">'.$dados['nome'] .'</h4>
                            '.$dados['cidade_nome'] .'

                            <p>'.$dados['descricao'] .'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="featured-offer-back">
                        <div id="featured-map1" class="featured-offer-map"></div>
                            <div class="button">
                            <a href="estate-details-right-sidebar.html" class="button-primary">
                                <span>read more</span>
                                <div class="button-triangle"></div>
                                <div class="button-triangle2"></div>
                                <div class="button-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            ';
        }
    ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

O mapa deve ser exibido na div 'featured-map1', como são varios registros, o nome dessa div acredito deverá ser dinâmico, como relaciona-la com a inicialização do javascript?

Comment: Coloca o código, ficaria mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tanto pensar, resolvi.

Dentro do while php, crio uma div com o nome 'list_map_'

Inicio o JavaScript em outro While na index desta forma

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
function init() {

    var locations = [

        <?php
            $coordenadas_sql = mysql_query(
            "
                SELECT
                       cidade.id AS id_cidade,
                       cidade.name AS cidade_nome,
                       empresa.nome
                FROM
                       cidade, empresa
                WHERE
                       id_cidade = cidade.id AND
                       empresa.nome = 'blablabla'
            ");
                while($coordenadas_dados = mysql_fetch_array($coordenadas_sql))
                {
                    echo '['.$coordenadas_dados['coordenada'].',"images/pin.png"],';
                }
        ?>
    ];
            <?php
                $coordenadas_sql = mysql_query(
                "
                SELECT
                       cidade.id AS id_cidade,
                       cidade.name AS cidade_nome,
                       empresa.nome
                FROM
                       cidade, empresa
                WHERE
                       id_cidade = cidade.id AND
                       empresa.nome = 'blablabla'
                ");
                    while($coordenadas_dados = mysql_fetch_array($coordenadas_sql))
                    {
                        echo 'mapInit('.$coordenadas_dados['coordenada'].',"list_map_'.$coordenadas_dados['id_cidade'].'","images/pin.png", false);';
                    }
            ?>
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente bem